# ASP.Net MVC 3..0 Razor Property value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, properties

can i set value for a property like this

```
public string MyProperty { get { return _GetValue(); } set { _GetValue(); } }


 public static string _GetValue()
    {
        string name = null;
        using (HROEF.Entities context = new HROEF.Entities())
        {
            var result = (from my linq Statement).First().ToString();
            name = result;
        }
        return name;
    }
```

In my View

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model=>Model.MyProperty)
```

is there any thing wrong in this?

It is not displaying the value in my view

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you shouldn't be doing database accessin properties.  It's just bad practice.  Properties should not perform lengthy operations that can time out, or have other issues.

As for why it's not showing your value, that's hard to say.  Most likely, your linq query simply isn't returning any results.

Comment: That make sense. Because it was working first time when i wrote that linq query in property but later it stopped showing. Any ways that for informing not to use this approach.